# Iphone HTML5 Geolocation always return a error

Tags: iphone, html, safari, geolocation, mobile-safari

I trying to use html5 geolocation on Iphone, but it always returns a error.

> var win = function(position) { alert('Everything is fine! ' + position) };
>   
>   var fail = function(e) { alert('Can\'t retrieve position.\nError: ' + e) };
>   
>   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(win, fail);

I testing on IOS Simulator and my device, but doesnt work.
On Safari i just can get my position using a wireless internet connection (??).

**There's a way to make this work?**

Answer (score 18):

Make sure that your Location Services on the device are on for Safari.  Go to *Settings > Privacy > Location Services > Safari* and make sure it is set to `ON`.

Then try this code:

```
function doGPS()
{
    try{
        //position request
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function (position) { 
        alert(position.coords.latitude);
        alert(position.coords.longitude);
        });
    }
    catch(evt)
    {
        alert(evt.message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Turning on location services worked for me. I tried testing it at: http://html5demos.com/geo  **Question:** is location services for safari turned on or off by default?

Answer (score 0):

I've used appMobi's js, and it works fine if I reload a site in Safari on the iPhone.  However, home screen bookmarked apps aren't doing it (even if I bookmark a new version on the web app).

The new js is loading into the bookmarked app fine (I added a pop up message with a new prompt each time I updated the code, just to make sure the web app is loading the new js), and the iPhone promtps me if I want to allow the site to check, but nothing happens when I say yes.  Whereas in Safari, it displays the lat/long.

Anyone had a similar problem?

UPDATE:  it works, but only the first time you load a page - the second time through, it displays 'start', but won't display the lat/long...

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  alert('Geolocation is supported!');
}
else {
  alert('Geolocation is not supported for this Browser/OS version yet.');
}

try{
    //position request
   alert('start');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function (position) { 
    alert(position.coords.latitude);
    alert(position.coords.longitude);
    });
}
catch(evt)
{
    alert('fail'+evt.message);
}
```